# Simultaneous equations using sympy python

Tags: python, sympy

I have pasted the code as well as the image of the output below. I keep getting 'm' and 'c' in the output instead of getting the values for m and c. Why is this happening?

```
import math
from sympy import solve, Eq
from sympy.abc import m, c
import sympy as sym

std = 100
std_half = std/2

m,c = sym.symbols('m,c')

eq1 = sym.Eq(0-(math.log(g_value3/g_value2)),(m*std_half)+c)       #y=mx+c, where y is absorbance, x is known concentration
eq2 = sym.Eq(0-(math.log(g_value4/g_value2)),(m*std)+c)

result = sym.solve([eq1,eq2],(m,c))

conc = ((0-math.log(g_value1/g_value2))-c)/m    #re-arranging y=mx+c in order to get x which is the concentration[![This is the output I'm getting][1]][1]
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. What are `g_value2` and `g_value3`? Further, you need to understand that sympy doesn't like other mathematical modules. So replace `math.log` with Sympy's `log`.

Answer (score 0):

`solve` doesn't *assign* a value, it *determines* a value and assigns it to the output (which you have stored as `result`). I you want to see what `conc` is with the values of `m` and `c` that are in `result`, I recommend that you use `dict=True` with `solve` and do as shown below:

```py
result = sym.solve([eq1,eq2],(m,c),dict=True)  # get a list of one or more dict
conc = ((0-math.log(g_value1/g_value2))-c)/m  # c and m are still symbols
print([conc.subs(r) for r in result])  # replaces c and m with values from solve
```